# Android memory usage keeps increasing while using app

Tags: java, kotlin, socket.io, android-jetpack-compose

I have developed a compose app which retrieves crypto data (a list of 1063 objects) from Socket each 3 seconds. While using app I recognized that after some time working with app it crashes with Out of memory. I profiled my app (release version) and recognized that while using app java code increase until it crashes with OOM error.

[image: Profiler]

Let me show you some code for better understanding.
For socket, I created a SocketManager class which instantiates on app startup via Dagger Hilt in singleton component.

```
    class SocketManager @Inject constructor(
    socket: Socket,
    private val json: Json
    ) {
    var cryptoFlow = MutableStateFlow<List<CryptoDataSetItemDto>>(emptyList())
    
    init {
        socket.connect()
        socket.on("crypto_data") {
            it.forEach { data ->
                try {
                    val coinList =
                        json.decodeFromString<List<CryptoDataSetItemDto>>(data.toString())
                    cryptoFlow.tryEmit(coinList)
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    Sentry.captureException(e)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}



@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object SocketModule {

@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideJson(): Json {
    return Json {
        encodeDefaults = true
        ignoreUnknownKeys = true
    }
}

@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideSocket(client: OkHttpClient): Socket {
    val socket: Socket
    val opts = IO.Options()
    opts.path = Constants.SOCKET_PATH
    opts.secure = true
    socket = IO.socket(Constants.SOCKET_BASE_URL, opts)
    return socket
}

@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideSocketManager(socket: Socket, json: Json): SocketManager {
    return SocketManager(socket, json)
}

}
```

Then I inject SocketManager to viewModel to get data on the screens I need those data. I create a function which gets a coroutine context from composable and collects data in that scope.

```
    @HiltViewModel
class WithdrawDepositViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val useCase: WalletUseCases,
    private val socketManager: SocketManager,
    savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
) : ViewModel() {

fun getCoinData(context: CoroutineContext) {
    CoroutineScope(context).launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
        socketManager.cryptoFlow.asStateFlow()
            .shareIn(CoroutineScope(context), SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed())
            .collectLatest { cryptoListDto ->
                val cryptoList = cryptoListDto.map { it.toCryptoList() }.toMutableList()
                val irt = CryptoDataItem(
                    enName = "Toman",
                    faName = "تومان",
                    symbol = "IRT"
                )
                cryptoList.add(0, irt)
                _state.value = state.value.copy(
                    cryptoList = cryptoList,
                    isLoading = false
                )
            }
    }
}
```

and in screen I call the function like this:

```
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(
    onNavigate: (String) -> Unit,
    scaffoldState: ScaffoldState,
    viewModel: HomeScreenViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {

val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
val lifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current
DisposableEffect(key1 = lifecycleOwner) {
    val observer = LifecycleEventObserver { _, event ->
        if (event == Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE) {
            viewModel.getCryptoData(scope.coroutineContext)
        }
    }
    lifecycleOwner.lifecycle.addObserver(observer)
    onDispose {
        lifecycleOwner.lifecycle.removeObserver(observer)
    }
}
}
```

This is my architecture to get data. when looked at heap dump result, I recognized that CryptoDataSetItemDto object which I get it on socket, has allocated lots of memory. I can not find the problem also I know that there is better architecture which I hope to learn from you.

Comment: @PylypDukhov thank you for your suggestion. I replaced code with images.

Comment: @Abhimanyu Thanks for your suggestion. I replaced images with code

Comment: @RezaFaraji, can you try replacing `Dispatcher.Default` with `Dispatchers.IO` in `getCoinData`? I am not sure if that is related, but network data fetching is an IO operation,